# Having a issue in showing angle quotation mark in firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, browser, character-encoding

I am having one widget in which I am trying to display text along with angle quotation mark-right(») character. A text inside this widget is following.

```
Begin Typing Here »
```

It's being displayed correctly in Firefox (in windows + Ubuntu), but in one of our Mac machine in Firefox + Chrome, "»" is not being displayed correctly.

I already have verified the default encoding that is set into Firefox in Mac. It's same as my ubuntu and windows machine's firefox.

**EDITS:**

I have following present in my HTML.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Here's screenshot of issue on Mac.

[image: Screen Shot]

Can someone share some random thoughts on this?

Comment: So how *is* it displayed on Mac? What *is* the character encoding, and where do you declare it?

Comment: It's displaying some weird characters in Mac. I have updated question about declaration in my HTML, have a look over there..thx..

Comment: Which weird characters exactly? And what do the HTTP headers say about the encoding? Are you sure the data is actually UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Trying to get image from Mac machine..will post it shortly..

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela added screenshot..pls..have a look on it..

Comment: The characters in the screenshot are U+00AC NOT SIGN and U+00AA FEMININE ORDINAL INDICATOR, so it seems that the browsers is interpreting according to some 8-bit encoding. The UTF-8 encoded form of “»” is 0xC2 0xBB, so it is difficult to see how it could be misinterpreted that way without at least two wrong conversions. Anyway, can you post the HTTP `Content-Type` header and/or specify the URL?

Comment: In response header "Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8"

Comment: Very strange then. If it happens on single computer on a single browser only, then the browser might be somehow broken. Is there any chance that the server sends different responses to different browsers?

Comment: I think browser version could be different..also I don't think so that server is sending different response to different browsers. But thanks..I'll verify the browser version and will check it if its broken.